# Mounting NFSv4 NAS folders hangs

Tags: mount, nfs, nfsv4

I have a QNAP NAS sharing folders using NFSv4. Until now I used to mount my folders as follows:

```
$sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 192.168.1.50:/Music ~/Music/
```

`192.168.1.50` is the IP of my NAS and `192.168.1.2` is the IP for my PC.

Everything was working perfectly until I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and it stopped working (I have touched absolutely nothing on the NAS server!).

If I run it with the `-v` parameter, the output is as follows:

```
$sudo mount -t nfs -o nfsvers=4 192.168.1.50:/Music ~/Music/    
mount.nfs: timeout set for Sun Apr 24 12:34:04 2022
mount.nfs: trying text-based options 'vers=4.2,addr=192.168.1.50,clientaddr=192.168.1.2'.
```

And it hangs like this, even if I leave it waiting for 1 hour. Finally I have to cancel by pressing `Control`+`C`.

I have tried disabling NFSv4 and using version 3, and in that case it does work (but I need to use version 4).

Any idea? Thanks!

---

Here are attached some outputs of different commands, in case it is helpful:

```
$sudo rpcinfo -p 192.168.1.50
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100011    1   udp  30002  rquotad
    100011    2   udp  30002  rquotad
    100011    1   tcp  30002  rquotad
    100011    2   tcp  30002  rquotad
    100005    1   udp  30000  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  30000  mountd
    100005    2   udp  30000  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  30000  mountd
    100005    3   udp  30000  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  30000  mountd
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100024    1   udp  30001  status
    100024    1   tcp  30001  status

$sudo showmount --exports 192.168.1.50
Export list for 192.168.1.50:
/Music 192.168.1.2
```